# I want to find a Dramione​ one shot fanfiction

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, dramione

I have been trying to find it for the past 5 years or so, in vain. It's on fanfiction.net . One shot. I remember it vaguely. 
But I hope it helps.
It's post war I think, every one's back for the last year or something.

Draco is alone, no more popular.
Draco is sitting by the black lake. Hermione happens to run into him. They have a civil conversation. And Hermione asks him "what is his biggest fear ?" To which he replies that "he's afraid he'd drown and die".

Conversations ends and they go back to their ways.
Few days later, Hermione sees Draco by the black lake sitting on some stone, from her Gryffindor tower's window.
She sees him jumping into the lake, afraid he might drown, she runs all the way from tower to the black lake.
When she gets there, Draco's nowhere in sight. She's shouting for him, thinking he drowned. But he gets above the water, and asks her what she's doing here.
She says she thought he drowned, reminding him what he told her the other day.
Then he says, that he's afraid of drowning doesn't mean he cannot swim. Some conversation and a kiss.
The end.

Sorry for the long description but I hope you find it.
It might not be a great piece of work but I love it all the same.

Comment: I'm at a loss why this attracted downvotes. I guess that some people don't like the idea of their precious Hermione being attracted to Draco :-)

Comment: @Valorum Or vice versa. I UV'd as these kind of questions are a great source of entertainment for me :)

Answer (score 6):

This is [**Blood, Tears and Drowning Fears**](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/140349/2/Blood-Tears-and-Drowning-Fears).

- Hermione asks Draco what he's afraid of...

  > *"You're right," Hermione finally said, fighting to keep her voice
  >   steady although undisguised hurt glistened in her eyes. "What the hell
  >   do I see in you? You're not even vaguely human, Malfoy, because humans
  >   have feelings and you obviously lack that. Humans feel pain and fear
  >   and pity and love, but all these are below you." Hermione caught the
  >   protest on Draco's face, but surged on defiantly, "That's true, Malfoy
  >   and you know it. Can you even tell me one thing you fear, or would it
  >   kill you too much just to say there's something you're actually afraid
  >   of?"*
  >
  > ***Draco tilted his head contemplatively, as if momentarily lost in
  >   thought. Finally, he spoke quietly. "Drowning."***
- He jumps into the water. Hermione is concerned...

  > *"Yes," she said tiredly, too weary to keep up facades or pretences
  >   anymore. "I saw you from the window in Gryffindor Tower — I saw you
  >   jumping into the lake and I panicked and I thought you were going to
  >   drown, that's what you said you were afraid of, didn't you?"*
  >
  > *Draco's expression was inscrutable. **"I said I was scared of drowning,
  >   I never said I couldn't swim."***
- They then kiss

  > '*In life, you've got to take chances sometimes."
  >
  >   **Then he leaned over and kissed her.**
  >
  >   Hermione blinked, startled; her mind went completely blank, and all she knew was Draco's lips on hers, kissing her firmly yet gently, with a tenderness she never thought possible from him. Her first impulse to shove him away instantly dissolved, as rational thinking swiftly melted and gave way to long-denied feelings. The coolness of his mouth quickly warmed as she leaned into his kiss, closing her eyes, her right hand reaching up to touch his cheek as she kissed him back. Hermione was only vaguely aware of Draco's arms going around her shoulders, pulling her close, one hand holding the back of her head as he kissed her thoroughly.*

Comment: "*as he kissed her thoroughly*" Oh my god.

Comment: I'm really sorry you had to read this.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - I read it *thoroughly*.

Comment: I retract my statement then - you brought this on yourself.

Comment: Ohho ! Thankyou so much.

Comment: @Emsmie_M - You're welcome. Don't forget to press the accepted button, *thoroughly*.